# Raven index not ordering results by date

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

I've created a static index in Raven to retrieve a collection of documents ordered by a descending date but it's now working correctly. Here's the index as stored in Raven Studio:

```
docs.EventInfos.OrderByDescending(info => info.CreatedOn).Select(info => new {
    CreatedOn = info.CreatedOn,
    LogLevel = info.LogLevel,
    Message = info.Message
})
```

Here's a sample of the results:

```
Id               CreatedOn                    LogLevel  Message
EventInfos/7321  2013-05-27T22:11:21.3767681  Debug     FlexMembersh...
EventInfos/3696  2013-05-26T12:15:47.7347512  Debug     FlexRoleProv...
EventInfos/3695  2013-05-26T12:15:47.0015559  Info      CampaignFace...
EventInfos/7320  2013-05-27T22:11:21.1427696  Debug     FlexMembersh...
EventInfos/3694  2013-05-26T12:15:46.7987572  Info      POST | Campa...
EventInfos/7319  2013-05-27T22:11:20.8931712  Debug     FlexMembersh...
```

I'm not sure why it isn't ordering correctly or what I can do to fix it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ordering is applied at *query* time, not indexing time.

Comment: The problem here is that I just want to get the latest 1024 documents ordered by `CreatedOn`. If I do the ordering in the query, I'll get the first 1024 documents but not the latest ones.

Comment: Then try sorting ascending, not descending.